# Windows 7 / 2008 / 2003 / XP - How do I make a Desktop Shortcut to Logoff User?

Tags: windows, shortcut

In Windows XP or later, How do I make a Desktop Shortcut to Logoff User?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could put the following in a cmd file and put that on the desktop (text file with .cmd extension):

```
shutdown -l
```

You can type shutdown in the command prompt for other arguments to shutdown to do other things ( like actually shutdown, would be -s ).

If you want to give it the log off icon, copy and then do 'Paste *shortcut*' and you can then select change icon from the properties.  There is the shutdown icon in `%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll`

**Update:**
I had originally said to use .bat, but the [other Kyle (Smith)](https://serverfault.com/users/23124/kyle-smith) pointed out that this loads the DOS emulator, so it is slower.

Comment: You should use .cmd extensions, .bat is run inside the "DOS emulator".  You can tell the difference by running start > run > command vs running start > run > cmd.  The former is much slower.  (Certainly doesn't make a huge difference here, but it's a best-practice.

Comment: Oh, and I am only sure this works with XP, but probably works with others as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's quite possible that MS don't provide programmatic access to logoff (at least outside of tools like shutdown.exe), and also possible that the reason why is a very good one (potential for abuse, and you can just guarantee that someone somewhere will somehow manage to put it in their Startup Program Group).

Comment: That's just silly. There are a multitude of ways a user can programmatically log themselves off.  Tools like shutdown.exe are just making standard Win32 calls.  But you could just as easily make a WMI call, or write a vbscript.